# have problem with connection to soap server from php

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

For a client i need to make a connection between a accounting system an a custom build erp in PHP.

Connecting to the server is not a problem using soapClient :

```
$soapCl = new soapClient($wsdlPath, array("trace" => true));
$result = $soapCl->Authenticate($authentication);
```

Authentication works fine no problem so far.
But when i try to do additional calls to other functions i get errors.

example :

```
 $dossier = soapCl->ConnectToDossier($dossierKey);
```

After booming my head over this for more the  a day i think it has somethinf to do with loosing the session ? (statelass) and that i has to send the cookie with the requests? but don(t now how to implement that?

how can i get the cookie received with the first response and use it to send back ?

Any help is appriciated, and even will pay for a build solution that i can further use

Comment: Is `ConnectToDossier` a valid method/action/function defined in the WSDL?

Comment: If you already have your heart set on some sort of cookie then what is stopping you from using [`SoapClient::__setCookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setcookie.php) and the equally cryptic `__getCookies()`?

Comment: ConnectToDossier is indeed a valid method and i made the same in c# and there it works perfect so that is not the problem

Comment: if i use soapCl->__getCookies() i get a empty arrya back